# Return the k rows that appear the most

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I got this table

```
photo_id user_id tag
0        0       Car
0        0       Bridge
0        0       Sky
20       1       Car
20       1       Bridge
2        2       Bridge
2        2       Cat
1        3       Cat
```

I need to return the k tags that appear the most, WITHOUT USING LIMIT.

tie breaker for tags that appear the same number of times will be the lexicographically order (smallest will have the highest score).
I will need for each tag the number of tags he appeared as well.

for example, for the table above with k=2 the output should be:

```
Tag           #
Bridge        3
Car           2
```

and for k=4:

```
Tag           #
Bridge        3
Car           2
Cat           2
Sky           1
```

Comment: Can we see some example queries you may have written, as the question you have posted is not clear enough to establish what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Lets say k=2.
i need to return the 2 tags that appear the most, in this case i will want to return 

Car         2 
Bridge    2

now lets say k=3, now i will want to return the 3 tags that appear the most

Car      2
Bridge  2
Sky      1

etc.
hope it helped

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT, ORDER BY, LIMIT...

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?  What problems did you run into?  SO isn't a query writing or homework solving site.

Comment: Its ok, i know how it sounds but i am sitting on this for around 7 hours now with no luck solving this.
was doin my best to solve this but im just stuck.

Comment: Simple `SELECT *,effort FROM others WHERE homework = 'mine';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT t1.tag, COUNT(*) as mycount FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.tag
ORDER BY mycount DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Replace the limit ammount for your `k` var.

Comment: what mycount stand for in the query and where does the "k" comes into consideration ?

Comment: oh, and i can't use limit, sorry :(

Comment: they wont allow it in my exercise (trying to make things harder in my damn uni i guess)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting data into table:

```
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES
  (0,0,'Car'),
  (0,0,'Bridge'),
  (0,0,'Sky'),
  (20,1,'Car'),
  (20,1,'Bridge'),
  (0,0,'bottle');
```

To query:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(1) FROM new_table  
GROUP BY tag HAVING COUNT(1) = (
    SELECT MIN(c) FROM   
    (  
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS c FROM new_table GROUP BY tag   
    ) AS temp
)
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+  
| tag    | count(1) |  
+--------+----------+  
| bottle |        1 |  
| Sky    |        1 |  
+--------+----------+
```

Note : Get smallest count tag

Comment: This wont work as for k=1(in your example) i want it to return Bridge 2 since i got 2 appearences of Bridge and Car and Bridge is lexicography smaller them Car

Answer (score 0):

Although this is homework and we are not supposed to answer such questions (not till you've proved that attempted to solve it and not getting desired result), I got a little curious about not using `LIMIT` in this question, so I am posting here.

The idea is to rank the result and then select only rows whose rank are less than or equal to value `k` (as in your case). The rank column is like adding a `S.No.` (serial number) column to your result and selecting till desired number.

DDL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table(
  photo_id INTEGER, 
  user_id INTEGER, 
  tag VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO new_table VALUES 
  (0, 0, 'Car'),
  (0, 0, 'Bridge'),
  (0, 0, 'Sky'),
  (20, 1, 'Car'),
  (20, 1, 'Bridge'),
  (2, 2, 'Bridge'),
  (2, 2, 'Cat'),
  (1, 3, 'Cat');
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  tag, tag_count,
  @k := @k + 1 AS k
FROM (
  SELECT 
    tag, 
    COUNT(*) AS tag_count
  FROM new_table
  GROUP BY tag
  ORDER BY tag_count DESC
) AS temp, (SELECT @k := 0) AS k
WHERE @k < 2;
```

[Check this `SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41e3d/11).